# How to decompose the Unity camera projection matrix to get camera intrinsic in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, camera-calibration

I am using unity camera as a GameObject. I set up my camera from camera panel. For my project I need camera intrinsic parameters. I can get the camera projection matrix from Unity, which contains camera rotational and translational part. How can I get camera intrinsic matrix from camera projection matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck on this too. But there are some alternative methods to get the intrinsic. You could refer to [Wrong camera intrinsic parameters in captures.json](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.perception/issues/388) and Rawdreen proposed the method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).